# OpenGL - glload undefined reference to `wglGetProcAddress@4'

Tags: opengl, qt-creator, glload

I downloaded the [Unofficial OpenGL SDK](http://glsdk.sourceforge.net/docs/html/index.html) and created the Makefile with premake4 and compiled it with mingw 4.8.4.

I am also using QtCreator

this is my .pro file

```
TEMPLATE = app

QT += opengl

SOURCES += main.cpp

QMAKE_CXXFLAGS += -std=gnu++11

INCLUDEPATH += C:/glsdk/freeglut/include
LIBS += -LC:/glsdk/freeglut/lib -lfreeglut

INCLUDEPATH += C:/glsdk/glload/include
LIBS += -LC:/glsdk/glload/lib -lglloadD
```

I am also follwing the arcsynthesis openGL tutorials and tried to build the "hello triangle example":

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <glload/gl_3_3.h>
#include <glload/gll.hpp>
#include <GL/freeglut.h>

using namespace std;


GLuint CreateShader(GLenum eShaderType, const std::string &strShaderFile)
{
    GLuint shader = glCreateShader(eShaderType);
    const char *strFileData = strShaderFile.c_str();
    glShaderSource(shader, 1, &strFileData, NULL);

    glCompileShader(shader);

    GLint status;
    glGetShaderiv(shader, GL_COMPILE_STATUS, &status);
    if (status == GL_FALSE)
    {
        GLint infoLogLength;
        glGetShaderiv(shader, GL_INFO_LOG_LENGTH, &infoLogLength);

        GLchar *strInfoLog = new GLchar[infoLogLength + 1];
        glGetShaderInfoLog(shader, infoLogLength, NULL, strInfoLog);

        const char *strShaderType = NULL;
        switch(eShaderType)
        {
        case GL_VERTEX_SHADER: strShaderType = "vertex"; break;
        case GL_GEOMETRY_SHADER: strShaderType = "geometry"; break;
        case GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER: strShaderType = "fragment"; break;
        }

        fprintf(stderr, "Compile failure in %s shader:\n%s\n", strShaderType, strInfoLog);
        delete[] strInfoLog;
    }

    return shader;
}

GLuint CreateProgram(const std::vector<GLuint> &shaderList)
{
    GLuint program = glCreateProgram();

    for(size_t iLoop = 0; iLoop < shaderList.size(); iLoop++)
        glAttachShader(program, shaderList[iLoop]);

    glLinkProgram(program);

    GLint status;
    glGetProgramiv (program, GL_LINK_STATUS, &status);
    if (status == GL_FALSE)
    {
        GLint infoLogLength;
        glGetProgramiv(program, GL_INFO_LOG_LENGTH, &infoLogLength);

        GLchar *strInfoLog = new GLchar[infoLogLength + 1];
        glGetProgramInfoLog(program, infoLogLength, NULL, strInfoLog);
        fprintf(stderr, "Linker failure: %s\n", strInfoLog);
        delete[] strInfoLog;
    }

    for(size_t iLoop = 0; iLoop < shaderList.size(); iLoop++)
        glDetachShader(program, shaderList[iLoop]);

    return program;
}

GLuint theProgram;

const std::string strVertexShader(
    "#version 330\n"
    "layout(location = 0) in vec4 position;\n"
    "void main()\n"
    "{\n"
    "   gl_Position = position;\n"
    "}\n"
);

const std::string strFragmentShader(
    "#version 330\n"
    "out vec4 outputColor;\n"
    "void main()\n"
    "{\n"
    "   outputColor = vec4(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);\n"
    "}\n"
);

void InitializeProgram()
{
    std::vector<GLuint> shaderList;

    shaderList.push_back(CreateShader(GL_VERTEX_SHADER, strVertexShader));
    shaderList.push_back(CreateShader(GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER, strFragmentShader));

    theProgram = CreateProgram(shaderList);

    std::for_each(shaderList.begin(), shaderList.end(), glDeleteShader);
}

const float vertexPositions[] = {
    0.75f, 0.75f, 0.0f, 1.0f,
    0.75f, -0.75f, 0.0f, 1.0f,
    -0.75f, -0.75f, 0.0f, 1.0f,
};

GLuint positionBufferObject;
GLuint vao;


void InitializeVertexBuffer()
{
    glGenBuffers(1, &positionBufferObject);

    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, positionBufferObject);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(vertexPositions), vertexPositions, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
}

//Called after the window and OpenGL are initialized. Called exactly once, before the main loop.
void init()
{
    InitializeProgram();
    InitializeVertexBuffer();

    glGenVertexArrays(1, &vao);
    glBindVertexArray(vao);
}


void display()
{
    glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    glUseProgram(theProgram);

    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, positionBufferObject);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
    glVertexAttribPointer(0, 4, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, 0);

    glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 3);

    glDisableVertexAttribArray(0);
    glUseProgram(0);

    glutSwapBuffers();
}
void reshape(GLsizei w,GLsizei h){
    GLint zero = 0;
    cout << "D ";
    glViewport(zero,zero,w,h);
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    glutInit(&argc, argv);

    int width = 500;
    int height = 500;
    unsigned int displayMode = GLUT_DOUBLE | GLUT_ALPHA | GLUT_DEPTH | GLUT_STENCIL;


    glutInitDisplayMode (displayMode);
    glutInitContextVersion (3, 3);
    glutInitContextProfile(GLUT_CORE_PROFILE);
#ifdef DEBUG
    glutInitContextFlags(GLUT_DEBUG);
#endif
    glutInitWindowSize (width, height);
    glutInitWindowPosition (300, 200);
    int window = glutCreateWindow (argv[0]);

    glload::LoadFunctions();

    glutSetOption(GLUT_ACTION_ON_WINDOW_CLOSE, GLUT_ACTION_CONTINUE_EXECUTION);

    if(!glload::IsVersionGEQ(3, 3))
    {
        printf("Your OpenGL version is %i, %i. You must have at least OpenGL 3.3 to run this tutorial.\n",
            glload::GetMajorVersion(), glload::GetMinorVersion());
        glutDestroyWindow(window);
        return 0;
    }

    if(glext_ARB_debug_output)
    {
        glEnable(GL_DEBUG_OUTPUT_SYNCHRONOUS_ARB);
        //glDebugMessageCallbackARB(DebugFunc, (void*)15);
    }

    init();

    glutDisplayFunc(display);
    glutReshapeFunc(reshape);
    //glutKeyboardFunc(keyboard);
    glutMainLoop();
    return 0;
}
```

But I always get the following error.

> c:\glsdk\glload\source\wgll_ext.c:140: error: undefined reference to
>   `wglGetProcAddress@4'

I don't even know why it looks in the glload\source folder.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is a *Windows* specific *OpenGL* function, are you developing a *Windows* application?

It seems those tutorials you are following are defined to work with *Windows* implementation of *OpenGL*, and they won't work with that *Unofficial OpenGL SDK* due to missing functions like `wglGetProcAddress`.